# Split ng-model values(javascript+angularjs)

Tags: javascript

I am getting input text box values in my angular ng-model as `903290,902020`. I want to insert this in mysql using nodejs with sequelize , so for bulk create i need array. How to convert this above `903290,902020` into  array `[903290,902020]`

Comment: `modelName.split(',')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function for this.

```js
var string = "903290,902020";
var split = string.split(",");

console.log(split)
```

Comment: will i get  this as array?

Comment: Yes, see the console output.